# Apply formula by calling function

Tags: excel, vba

I need help on my issue.

I have an Excel file with two sheets named as:

1.Hold

[image: Hold worksheet]

2.20Apr'20

[image]

I want to find 'all reason of the id' using lookup. The expected output as below:

[image]

I try to create a function to lookup all the reason value of the id, however the results is unsuccessful which i get **#Name** as result.

This is what I have so far.

```
Public Function Lookup_Concat(Search_ID As Range, Search_col As Range, Concat_del As String, Return_val_col As Range)
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim result As String
For i = 1 To Search_Col.Count
        For Each Value In Search_ID
            If Search_Col.Cells(i, 1) = Value Then
                result = result & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value & Concat_del
            End If
        Next Value
    Next i
    Lookup_Concat = Left(result, Len(result) - Len(Concat_del))

End Function



Sub Get_Reason()

WorkSheets("20Apr'20").Activate
Range("C:C" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=Lookup_Concat(=Lookup_concat(RC[-1]:R[4]C[-1],Hold!R[-1]C[-1]:R[6]C,"","",Hold!R[-1]C:R[6]C)"

End Sub
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Really appreciate if someone can help me on this.

Comment: `Range("C:C" & lastrow)` is no valid range address. It must either be `"C:C"` or a number after **both** column letters like `"C1:C10"` but what you did would end up with something like `"C:C10"` and that is not possible. • Also in your formula you need to double the quotes: `…:R[6]C,"","",Hold!R…` needs to be `…:R[6]C,"""","""",Hold!R…`

Comment: Can you include in your question with which parameters you call this UDF `Lookup_Concat` from your formula in the cell? • Also note that this approach might be very slow if you have a lot of data rows. For each formula that uses `Lookup_Concat` your code loops through the whole data. I recommend not to use a UDF for that but a button that does only one loop and write down all data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, Najaa, I can't make out what you intend to do. However, I hope and trust that the function below will help you progress by a tiny step. Give it a try.

```
Function GetReason(ID As Variant) As String
    ' 007

    Dim Rng As Range

    With Worksheets("20 Apr '20")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1))
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    GetReason = Application.VLookup(ID, Rng, 2, False)
End Function
```

The function is *Public* because all procedures are *Public* unless expressly declared as *Private*. It needs to be called with one parameter, like,

```
Dim MyString as String
MyString = GetReason(3)
' or
Debug.Print GetReason(3)
' or - directly in the Immediate Window
? GetReason(3)
```

It will return the value from column B on the `Hold` sheet where column A has the value `3`. Pay attention to the data type. If Hold!A:A has numbers, `GetReason("3")` will return nothing and v.v.

Now, if you want to use this function in your sheet `20Apr'20` You can call the function as shown below.

```
With Worksheets("20Apr'20")
    .Cells(2, "B").Value = GetReason(.Cells(2, "A").Value)
End With
```

Of course, this can be put into a loop. But normally one wouldn't do that. Instead, one would deploy a Change event procedure attached to column A so that the value in column B changes whenever the user enters something in column A. Since this procedure would be in the code sheet of tab "20Apr'20" the worksheet needs not be specified and the following code would suffice. You can install it for testing.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Rng As Range                ' range containing IDs
    Dim Cell As Range

    Set Rng = Range(Cells(2, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    If Not Application.Intersect(Rng, Target) Is Nothing Then
        ' don't support multi-column paste operations
        If Target.Columns.Count = 1 Then
            ' don't call this procedure on every change following here
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            For Each Cell In Target
                Cell.Offset(, 1).Value = GetReason(Cell.Value)
            Next Cell
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In fact, I have constructed this code to allow it to work in a loop using a little trick: Select all the IDs in column A, Press *Copy* (or *Ctl+C*) and then, leaving the selection as it is, immediately press *Ctl+V* to paste values to their original place. Excel will perceive this as a change and fill in the looked-up values in column B for all selected IDs.

Please see how far this gets you. I regret I didn't understand your intention around *Lookup_Concat* and *concat_del*.